# Make slideToggle effect only one element at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, expand

Here's what I've got so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/jackieschreiber/4XQJm/3/

```
$('.expand').on('hover', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$price = $('.price-box');
$priceFull = $price.find('.full');
$priceMini = $price.find('.small');

$priceFull.slideToggle('slow');

$(this).unbind('mouseenter');
});
```

My question is, if I've got multiple elements of this class, how do I only apply the effect to the one currently being hovered over?

Comment: Is it just me or does not jsFiddle example not do anything?

Comment: @j08691 I tried hovering over a bunch of things, but I was too lazy to look at the HTML and find what `.expand` is. I was thinking it was just me.

Comment: @OP the problem here is that you're looking for `.full` inside `.small`, whereas it is actually the parent of `.small`. Try using `.parent()`.

Comment: It does now, I forgot to save it as jquery @j08691

Answer (score 3):

Changed your selectors a little bit and added stopPropagation() so the animations wouldn't que.

http://jsfiddle.net/4XQJm/4/

```
$('.price-box').on('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.full').slideToggle('slow');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```